# Google optimize preview link does not work

Tags: google-optimize

Google optimize preview link does not show me the correct experience/Variation on my browser, instead shows the control version.

Answer (score 1):

Google Optimize preview has some limitations: It only works on Chrome & Safari.

1. To make sure it works on chrome incognito: you have to disable
   “Block third-party cookies”

   [image]
2. Or use “Guest mode” in chrome so plug-ins won’t interfere with your
   changes.
3. for Safari (go to Preferences > Privacy and uncheck “Prevent
   cross-site tracking”) to use preview mode [image]